# Update TextView with runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to have a timer on my Game Activity. The Timer-Thread needs to be in an other class not in my Activity. I've tryed this but it only shows me the first miliseconds and doesn't update than.

```
public class GameTimer implements Runnable {

private double count = 0.00;

@Override
public void run(){
    while(true){
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
            count += 0.01;
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
}
public String getCountAsString(){
    return new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(count);
}
}
```

in Activity

```
Thread tf = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                timerTextView.setText(controller.getGameTimer().getCountAsString());
            }
        });
    }
};
initGameyard();
Thread testThread = new Thread(controller.getGameTimer());
testThread.start();
tf.start();
```

Comment: Thread updating the TextView value runs only once. You need to repeat it in a way or other for longer time.

Comment: there is my problem. It's not "my" thread so i don't know how to repeat that thread.

Comment: Why do you need a thread at all?  Are you doing some havy things in it?

Comment: just my Timer atm. I think ill just implement it in my activity, this will make things easier :)

Comment: If you don't need a thread use a lightweight Handler to do repetitive tasks

Answer (score 0):

You can add the TextView as a parameter in GameTimer constructor like so :

```
public GameTimer(TextView tv) {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(10);
            count += 0.01;
            tv.setText(count + "");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
        }
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason why i dont implement that thread in the activity is that i try to use the MVC-Architectural pattern, so giving the Textview as a parameter woulnt be nice ...